# How to document a database project in visualstudio

Tags: sql, visual-studio, documentation, database-project

Based on my knowledge about c# documentation via Visual studio i activated the xml file in Properties -> SQLCLR-Build -> XML-Documentationfile.

now the xml file is created but i'm unable to figure out what tags are allowed and how to start the documentation

in c# i would do

```
/// <summary>
/// does some stuff
/// </summary>
public ....
```

so i did the same in sql

```
--- <summary>
--- does some stuff
--- </summary>
CREATE PROCEDURE ....
```

but the created xml doesn't reflect my documentation.

and even after some research about "visual studio SQLCLR build xml documentation" i'm unable to find some useful information on **how to document my procedures, tables and functions** in a way that the xml-documention is able to catch it

I'm using visual studio 2013 just in case this is importent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of ideas:

1. There is a project on codeproject.com called [SQL XML Documentation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21271/SQL-XML-Documentation) that extracts XML comments from SQL scripts using Microsoft SandCastle. I've never used it though so I cannot vouch for it.
2. If you don't necessarily need the documentation in XML, you can take advantage of the Description property in Visual Studio's Property pane. The description will be stored as an extended property in SQL Server.
   [image]

Comment: Thx for for both way's, the second one only works for Tables.

So there is no native way to documenting my procedures in visual studio even if the have this CheckBox to activate the XML output?

I will check your First suggestion because it looks like it fit's my needs, for the moment +1 :-)

Comment: @WiiMaxx Right, there's no native way to do this in VS. That checkbox applies to just CLR assemblies.